# Vista Workstation Creates Documents folder on 2003 File Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-vista, file-sharing, mappeddrive

I have a lab of notebook running vista they map to a h drive on a windows 2003 server r2.
The users that have xp dont have this issue but the vista users home drives changed their structure on the windows 2003 server from X:\home\username to X:\home\Documents.

When you check the file permissions on the "documents" folder it has that users permissions and if you type X:\home\username you get the contents of the H drive however from a admin perspective having 30 users with X:\home\Documents its tough to find which one is for which user.

It all functions correctly (drives map etc) but it is just messy.
Has anyone else had this problem?

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: have you redirected their documents from their profile?

Comment: No There is no redirection.  I know it is recommended to just redirect my docs to a UNC but because there are only 30 odd machines on vista I want to wait till we are no longer using windows xp (if 7 is the cure)

Answer (score 1):

I will agree this is messy.  You could fix this temporarily by deleting all the `X:\home\username\desktop.ini` files, which is what tells Window Explorer to display a special name/icon for the folder.  But windows will just re-create these.  You could possible replace/modify the content of your `desktop.ini` files with something that doesn't change the name/icon, but am not sure what you would want to change it to.

What we have done to make this less messy, is to just make a users Documents folder exit deeper.  So instead of having Documents go to `X:\home\username` you send them to `X:\home\username\Documents` in any of your folder redirection policies or user settings.  This does mean changing lots of paths though and probably breaking lots of shortcuts in the processes.